# Export multiple FC's to cad in arcobjects C#

Tags: arcobjects, cad

I am currently trying to export multiple feature classes to a single .dxf via the QuickExport function in the DataInteroperability extension. However this function only converts one FC to one .dxf, ie. One in, one out.

Can someone point me to another function that allows multiple files to be converted to a single output format?

I have tried using a list as an input but to no avail. I know of the ExportToCAD function in python. Is there something similar in C#?.

[EDIT]
Here is some code I have been playing around with. I decided to simply use the ExportCAD function in the ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools namespace.

```
        try
        {
            IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
            IMap map = mxdoc.FocusMap as IMap;

            ITrackCancel tc = new TrackCancel();

            for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
            {
                List<string> layerInputList = new List<string>();
                ILayer pLayer = map.Layer[i];
                if (!(pLayer is IGroupLayer))
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < map.LayerCount; j++)
                    {
                        ILayer layer = map.Layer[j];
                        if (layer is IGroupLayer)
                        {
                            IGroupLayer groupLayer = layer as IGroupLayer;
                            ICompositeLayer compGroupLayer = groupLayer as ICompositeLayer;

                            for (int k = 0; k < compGroupLayer.Count; k++)
                            {
                                ILayer featLayer = compGroupLayer.Layer[k];
                                layerInputList.Add("C:\\Users\\jhansen\\Documents\\LGA_GDBs\\" + pLayer.Name + ".gdb\\" + featLayer.Name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
                    ExportCAD exportCAD = new ExportCAD();

                    exportCAD.in_features = layerInputList;
                    exportCAD.Output_File = "C:\\Users\\jhansen\\Documents\\LGA_GDBs\\" + pLayer.Name + "_CAD.dxf";
                    exportCAD.Output_Type = "DXF_R14";

                    gp.Execute(exportCAD, tc);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.Source + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

And here is the error I get
[image]
suggesting that it falls over at the `gp.execute()` line

I suspect this has something to do with the list variable I am using at `exportCAD.inputfeatures`.

Comment: You can call that with IGeoprocessor, that's about the only thing I can think of.. The quick export function supports a list of inputs (see http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001600000004000000) so send it a list of feature classes and it *should* put them all into a CAD file.. can you post some code so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Michael suggestions,

Here is your solution. Copy and paste may not work, since I haven't tested the code

```cs
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
parameters.Add(@"D:\mydb.gdb\myFeatuerClass1;D:\mydb.gdb\myFeatuerClass2"); 
parameters.Add("DWG_R2007"); 
parameters.Add(@"C:\temp\ExportCAD.DWG"); 

Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
bool response = RunTool("ExportCAD_conversion", parameters, null, false);

public static bool RunTool(string toolName,IVariantArray parameters , ITrackCancel TC, bool showResultDialog)
{
    Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
    IGeoProcessorResult result = null;
    // Execute the tool            
    try
    {
        result = (IGeoProcessorResult)gp.Execute(toolName, parameters, TC);
        string re = result.GetOutput(0).GetAsText(); 
        if (showResultDialog)
            ReturnMessages(gp);
        if (result.MaxSeverity == 2) //error
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    } 
    catch (COMException err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message + " in RunTool"); 
        ReturnMessages(gp);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message + " in RunTool"); 
        ReturnMessages(gp);
    }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work try parameters.Add(@"[D:\mydb.gdb\myFeatuerClass1,D:\mydb.gdb\myFeatuerClass2]"); as a python style list... the old way was strings with a semi colon but nowdays python style lists seem to be the way. It's hard to tell (sometimes) how the tool wants it so try one way then if that gives an error try the other, then, if that still doesn't work post the code on GIS.StackExchange with the error message.

Comment: This did work. I found an issue with my for loop in that it was referencing the .dxf that was added to the mxd after creation.