# Can not export some annotaton layers using QuickExport in ArcObjects.NET

Tags: arcobjects, export, data-interoperability

I develops add-in for ArcMap that exports different layers to `.mif` format using `ESRI.ArcGIS.DataInteroperabilityTools.QuickExport`

```cs
Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
gp.OverwriteOutput = true;
QuickExport qe = new QuickExport();
qe.Input = layerPath;
qe.Output = string.Format("MIF, {0}", exportPath);
gp.Execute(qe, null); // error is here
```

Common geometry layers (points, lines, polygons) are exports without any problems.

But I get `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component` when tries export some annotation layers, and some annotation layers exports successfully. Inner exception is null.
Haw can I debug this error?
What difference could be between annotations?
And what could be reason of such behaviour?

**Update:**

Also I tried [such way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148511/export-multiple-fcs-to-cad-in-arcobjects-c):

```cs
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
parameters.Add(layerPath);
parameters.Add(string.Format("MIF, {0}", exportPath));
RunTool("QuickExport_interop", parameters, null, false);

public static bool RunTool(string toolName, IVariantArray parameters, ITrackCancel TC, bool showResultDialog)
{
    Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
    IGeoProcessorResult result = null;
    // Execute the tool            
    try
    {
        result = (IGeoProcessorResult)gp.Execute(toolName, parameters, TC); // error is here
        string re = result.GetOutput(0).GetAsText();
        if (showResultDialog)
            ReturnMessages(gp);
        if (result.MaxSeverity == 2)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    catch (COMException err)
    {
        string message = err.Message;
        Exception e = err.InnerException;
        while (e != null)
        {
            message += "\n" + e.Message;
            e = e.InnerException;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(message + " in RunTool");
        ReturnMessages(gp);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message + " in RunTool");
        ReturnMessages(gp);
    }
    return false;
}

private static void ReturnMessages(Geoprocessor gp)
{
    if (gp.MessageCount > 0)
    {
        for (int Count = 0; Count <= gp.MessageCount - 1; Count++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(gp.GetMessage(Count));
        }
    }

}
```

But result was same as in first way.

`QuickExport` tool works only in ArcPy for me both for annotation layers and common geometry layers:

```py
arcpy.QuickExport_interop(layer_path, 'MIF, {}'.format(export_path))
```

Comment: Is this an addin or standalone application? Which line does the error occur on? Sometimes you get this error when licensing has not been set up properly. I think you need to give us a little more information about your project.

Comment: I updated code and showed error lines. I sure that problem is not with licensing - I can successfully export and get error during one session. Problems are with annotation layers only.